# 3D nonogram, beginner's edition

Tags: visual, grid-deduction, three-dimensional, nonogram

Trying out the concept of 3D nonograms. This one should be pretty simple.

> [image]

Name the depicted object.

Comment: very innovative and fun idea! +1!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I think that this is one of the quiet hours on PE so I would expect more votes in a couple hours. It is sad though that some good quality questions can have potential traction killed

Comment: Instructions:

Imagine a stack with five layers. Each of the five diagrams with numbers aside represent one layer from the top to the bottom of the stack. The numbers within the diagram belong to the line at the corresponging position from the top to the bottom through all layers of the stack. 11 means one-one not eleven!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

nonogram:

> [image]

this is depicting

> a 6-sided dice!

Comment: All correct. Nice job!